# Why the probability of an empty slot preceded by i full slots getting filled next is (i + 1)/m in context of Primary clustering in Hashing?

Tags: algorithm, hash

Why the probability of an empty slot preceded by i full slots getting filled next is  (i + 1)/m in context of Primary clustering in Hashing with Open addressing as collision resolution technique and linear probing? This is the excerpt from Introduction to Algorithms CLRS "Long runs of occupied slots build up, increasing the average search time. Clusters arise because an empty slot preceded by i full slots gets filled next with probability (i + 1)/m. Long runs of occupied slots tend to get longer,and the average search time increases." Please help.

Comment: Known as the "parking problem". Viola has a nice summary, including references (including Knuth) http://aofa2013.lsi.upc.edu/slides/Viola.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think i got the answer to it.

For the empty slot (say j) preceded by i full slots to get filled next an element should hash to any of the i slots or slot j.
The book says:

> we shall assume that any given element is equally likely to hash into any of the m slots, independently of where any other element has hashed to.

i.e. Probability that an element hashes to any slot k is 1/m.

So, **Required probability** would be

( 1/m + 1/m + ... i times ) + 1/m {for slot j} = (i+1)/m